# using instance variables that created as a parameter inside the class method

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Sorry for asking something basic, but I couldn't figure out why I am unable to use the parameters inside the class method.

this is what I need help with.
API.h

```
@class User;
@interface API : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,readonly,retain)NSString *StoreIdentifierForVendor;
+(NSURLSessionDataTask *)MethodForMakingTheRequestWithBlock:(void(^)(NSString *username, NSError *error))block;
@end
```

APILibrary.m

```
@implementation API
@synthesize StoreIdentifierForVendor;
+(NSURLSessionDataTask *)MethodForMakingTheRequestWithBlock:(void(^)(NSString * username, NSError *error))block
{
    id loginDict = @{"NickName": username}
}
@end
```

The problem that I am having is, I don't understand why I am getting a "use of undeclared identifier 'username' error. I tried to set up as

```
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *username;
```

as well but, I was unable to put it as a parameter. Why I can not use the username in the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

The `username` variable has been declared as a parameter for a block and thus can be used inside that block only while you try to access it inside the method that has this block as a parameter. It's like trying to access a local variable in a global scope. It does not exist there

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a block to the method `MethodForMakingTheRequestForBlock`, and the block takes a parameter of type `NSString *`. The parameter happens to be called `username`, but that only means something inside the block.

Comment: what I am trying to create a method that gonna make a post request when I set the username from viewcontroller. So if I can not set it up like I am trying in loginDict, how I am supposed to do that?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the block here? Is it supposed to be executed when the data task completes? Why not just make a method like `-requestToCheckUsername:completionBlock:`?

Comment: @MarkAdams, I am trying to pass logicDict as a parameter here `return [[APIManager sharedManager] POST:@"stream/0/posts/stream/global" parameters:loginDict success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * __unused task, id JSON)...` and I am gonna set this method in the view controller once the user signs up.

Comment: Why don't you just make username parameter for the method itself, not for the block?